# Loop through an array of nested objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops

Im having trouble to print out objects that are inside of an array,
When im console logging this is what i get:

```
console.log(product.categories)
```

[image]

How would i be able to iterate through these nested objects where i could display these individually like

```
<ul>
  <li>Bath</li>
  <li>/bath/</li>
  <li>18</li>
  <li>Shop all</li>
  <li>/shop-all/</li>
  <li>23</li>
</ul>
```

The whole 'products' data object looks like this
[image]

Comment: Please provide sample data as text.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and the challenges it presents you with so we may assist you in fixing it.

Comment: I tried using the Object entries over the product.categories object like this
`    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(product.categories)) {
      console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
    }`

But all i got returned is "edges: [object Object],[object Object]"

Comment: @ScreamoIsDead because you are doing `Object.entries` on array, not object. Change `product.categories` -> `product.categories.edges` instead. You dont even need to use Object.entries. Dont forget that to print it to html is called toString method, so when object is present, toString() returns [object Object]

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the values of each object in the array, create list items from each of them, and append them to the list element.

```js
let obj = {
  edges: [
    {name: 'Bath', path: '/bath/', entityId: 18},
    {name: 'Shop App', path: '/shop-all/', entityId: 23}
  ]
}
let ul = document.createElement('ul');
for(const x of obj.edges) 
  for(const textContent of Object.values(x))
    ul.append(Object.assign(document.createElement('li'), {textContent}));
document.body.append(ul);
```

Answer (score 0):

## 2 Ways

---

There are 2 solutions I can think of at the moment.

### <Array>.forEach()

---

This solution is best if you want to log the individual elements of the array.
There's a better way for changing the array elements but let's look at the example.

```js
const arr = [{ name: "Home", path: "/home" }, { name: "Forums", path: "/forums" }];

arr.forEach((value) => {
    console.log(value);
});
// { name: "Home", path: "/home" }
// { name: "Forums", path: "/forums" }


// You can map it to a new value by doing this

const newArr = [];

arr.forEach((value) => {
    newArr.push(value.name);
});

console.log(newArr);
// ["Home", "Forums"]
```

### <Array>.map()

---

This is the best solution I would use.
This method changes the value of individual element to what returns in your function.

```js
const arr = [{ name: "Home", path: "/home" }, { name: "Forums", path: "/forums" }];

const newArr = arr.map((value) => value.name);
console.log(newArr);

// ["Home", "Forums"]
// Notice how the value has changed
```

---

## The Solution

Here's what the solution will look like

```
function YourComponent() {
    const edges = product.categories.edges;
    const products = edges.map((value) => [value.name, value.path, value.entityId.toString()]);

    return (
        {
            products.map((data) => {
                return (
                    <li>data[0]</li>
                    <li>data[1]</li>
                    <li>data[2]</li>
                );
            });
        }
    );
};
```